# In Vim, when doing vi", how do you only select things inside the quotes and not things between the quotes

Tags: vim, neovim

Take for example

```js
{ label: "Contacts", p|age: "/contacts" },
```

When the cursor is on `page`, doing `vi"` selects `, page:`  and not the subsequent quotee, `/contacts`.

What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: Vim hardly could distinguish opening/closing quotes when the quotes are the same. The only way to properly distinguish them is to have different opening/closing quotes like  `«»`, `„”`, `‘‚`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the behaviour you describe is expected and documented so there is no "issue" to speak of.

From `:help a"`:

```
Selects the text from the previous quote until the next quote.
```

What you want is something that doesn't exist in Vim, a "next text object" text object.

There are a few  old but still working snippets floating around for that (ask your favourite search engine), as well as [plugins](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim).